# kdb type error when inserting I as F

Tags: kdb

I have a certain file type that contains a column with floats which I read in using insert

```
`table insert ("TISISIFIIIFFIbIFFFFFFIIIFIIFFFFIIIIIIIIIIIIFFFFFFIIFFIIIIFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII"; enlist "\t" ) 0:`:my_file.txt
```

unfortunately, sometimes the values in column happen to be all integers and in the txt file the are saved as ints, not floats, so as 1 instead of 1.0 and it seems kdb is throwing a type error. Is there a way make kdb accept ints saved in that format as floats?

I do have a lot of columns with floats and theoretically, the problem can appear in any of them. Is there some way to tell kdb on insert to treat any int as float if the column type is float?

Comment: Have you used the `meta` function to double check the column data-types? I'm not able to reproduce the issue (on kdb+ 3.2)

Answer (score 2):

The 'type error is actually happening from your insert. You are trying to insert some parsed data, but the types of each column are not conforming to the types of each column in 'table'.
You are basically saying that your raw data can contain floats, therefore you are going to have to read them in as floats.
What you do with that column after the parse is up to you though.

1) keep as floats, read in as floats, insert as floats, column should be a float in 'table' pre-read (I presume this is what you want going by your question):

```
update "f"$COLUMN from `table
`table insert (1#"F";1#"\t") 0:`myfile.txt
```

2) update to an integer and then insert into 'table' - you are going to have update the schema of table first, read in as floats, and then run an update after every read:

```
update "i"$COLUMN from `table
`table insert update "i"COLUMN from (1#"F";1#"\t") 0:`myfile.txt
```

Another option you may want to consider, but please test first as it may replace too much, is to replace the trailing ".0" from your floats, and then just read in as integers:

```
q)\cd /var/tmp
q)`:myfile.txt 0:("x\tx1";"1.0\t2.0";"3.0\t1.0")
q)\sed -i -e 's/.0//g' myfile.txt
q)("II";1#"\t")0:`myfile.txt
```

Comment: I actually want to keep them as floats. the problem seems to be that some values are saved as ints as in the csv, round floats will be saved as ints, so, 115.0 will be saved as 115.

Comment: If some are saved as ints in the csv, you can read them all in as floats fine - just keep your column as a float, read them in as floats, and insert as floats (#1 above)